# Unable to install ZeroMQ in debian

Tags: debian

I tried to install ZeroMQ in my debian server using, apt-get install libzmq-dev and got the below output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libzmq-dev
```

Then I tried to add the repo using, add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/zeromq and got:

```
bash: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

Then I checked if I have python-software-properties installed.

```
apt-get install python-software-properties
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-software-properties is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Then I tried installing software-properties-common but it couldnt locate the package

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
```

What can I do next?

Answer (score 2):

> Then I tried to add the repo using, add-apt-repository
>   ppa:chris-lea/zeromq and got:

That is an invalid command. You should be using:

```
$ apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/zeromq
```

Comment: Tried same result : apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/zeromq
bash: apt-add-repository: command not found